# How to restrict data table to display 10 records at time instead of loading all the data once?

Tags: codeigniter, datatables

I have used the datatable for loading details from database in codeigniter.
I have more than 10000 records. The datatable loads all the data and then displays 10 records per page which takes more time for loading all the data.
is there anyway to load 10 records at a time next record should load after clicking on pagination link.

The view is

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-hover" id="sample_2">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="display:none">No.</th>
      <th>Product Name</th>
      <th>Category</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Customer Price</th>
      <th>Reseller Price</th>
      <th>Image</th>


    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php $i=1;
                 foreach($product['list'] as $row=>$value){ ?>
    <tr>
      <td style="display:none">
        <?php echo $i; $i++ ?>
      </td>

      <td>
        <?php  echo $product['list'][$row]->item_name;?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <?php  echo $product['list'][$row]->cat_name ;?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <?php echo $product['list'][$row]->quantity;?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <?php echo $product['list'][$row]->price;?>
      </td>
      <td>
        <?php echo $product['list'][$row]->reseller;?>
      </td>
      <td><img src="<?php echo base_url()." assets/uploads/ ".$product['list'][$row]->image;?>" height="50px" width="50px" border="1px solid #FFF">

      </td>

    </tr>

    <?php } ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Script is

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#sample_2').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
       
        buttons: [
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
        ]

    } );
} );
/*$(document).ready(function() {
        var data = [];
        for ( var i=0 ; i<1000000000 ; i++ ) {
            data.push( [ i, i, i, i, i ] );
        }
         
        $('#sample_2').DataTable( {
         dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: ['copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print']
           
        } );
    } );*/
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to datatable mechanism it shows 10 data per page as default value. You can change it by simply following this code.

```
$('#sample_2').dataTable( {
  "pageLength": 6 //per page it will show 6 data. 
} );
```

You can change it according to your wish. if you don't use **pageLength**. This will use 10 as default value inside datatable

Comment: will it load 6 records only for initial load or will load all data?

Comment: It will load all data from the database. But 6 records will be visible and this will be controlled by pageLength.

Answer (score 1):

In your SQL query use this. It will only show 6 records.

```
$this->db->limit(6);
```